# Complex or compound-complex?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

I don't understand what type of sentence is this. Is *"and"*  a coordinating conjunction here?
Is it a sentence with two relative clauses?

> "This is the reflection of who you are **and** who you have become despite all of those experiences."

Answer (score 0):

In abstract terms, this is a sentence which uses a form of the verb "**to be**" to link its subject to a subject complement. The basic structure is simple:

> "*X* is *Y*."

The subject is "**this**", and the main verb is "**is**". Simple, right? ... However, the subject complement ("*Y*"), is a little bit complex and consists of the entire phrase, "**the reflection of who you are and who you have become despite all of those experiences**".

This long-ish phrase might be confusing to an English learner. It is really just one simple noun ("**the reflection**"), but that noun is modified by the preposition "**of**" followed by *two* objects. So the structure of the whole sentence is essentially:

> "*X* is the *Y* of *A* and *B*."

Where "*A*" = "**who you are**"; and "*B*" = "**who you have become despite all of those experiences**".

The objects *A* & *B* are definitely clauses. When I looked up the grammar terms at [yourdictionary](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/nouns/noun-clause.html) and [Grammar Bytes](https://www.chompchomp.com/terms/relativeclause.htm), I discovered that they are both technically "*noun* clauses" (not *relative* clauses), because they act as nouns in the sentence, (and not as adjectives like "*relative* clauses" would).

So "**who you are**" and "**who you have become**" both act as nouns connected by the coordinating conjunction "**and**". The "**and**" gives both of them equal status and importance as the two things [actually *people*, both of them "you"] that are involved in the "reflection" named in the sentence.

Sorry for the wordy explanation, but the short answer is:

Yes, "**and**" is a coordinating conjunction. Yes, the sentence has two dependent clauses. But, no, they are technically "*noun* clauses" not "relative clauses".

Comment: "Who you are" and "who you have become" are best analysed as interrogatives (embedded questions).